# Visualize part of a complex message

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With rostopic you can echo subparts of a complex message easily by choosing `<topic name>/<field name>/<field name>`.

Is it possible to visualize only a subpart of a complex message in rviz?
For example if you have defined a message that contains a path, an image, and a pose can you visualize these in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10789/visualize-part-of-a-complex-message/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, you cannot do that.

Rviz is not set up to do that.  Part of the reason is that RVIZ is written in C++ and cannot do that kind of runtime introspection.  It needs to have the full message class compiled into its binary in order to be able to receive, deserialize, and manipulate the object.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3